# Using Swipe Recognizer in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, move, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to implement swipe gestures left and right into a game in SpriteKit where the player collects falling objects spawning from the top of the screen. The problem I'm facing is trying to keep a continuous movement of the player while the finger is on the screen until the touch is ended and the player stays where the last touch ended. There might be a better way to implement this other than swipe gestures hence why I'm asking you guys! Any help would be great, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you want to use a swipe (I think you are using pan) gesture for.  What you want to do is override the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` calls on the scene, and plan your movement according to these 3 methods.

You are probably going to want to use `SKAction.move(to:duration:)` with these methods, and figure out the math to keep a constant speed.

E.G.

```
func movePlayer(to position:CGPoint)
{
  let distance = player.position.distance(to:position)
  let move = SKAction.move(to:position, duration: distance / 100) // I want my player to move 100 points per second
  //using a key will cancel the last move action
  player.runAction(move,withKey:"playerMoving")
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) 
{
  let touch = touches.first
  let position = touch.location(in node:self)
  movePlayer(to:position)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) 
{
  let touch = touches.first
  let position = touch.location(in node:self)
  movePlayer(to:position)
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  let touch = touches.first
  let position = touch.location(in node:self)
  movePlayer(to:position)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works, thanks a lot dude! @KnightOfDragon